# Can I enforce Entity Framework loading all the data into memory in bunches?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there a build-in way in Entity Framework to enforce loading all the data into memory in bunches (like load only 50 entities per iteration) until there is nothing left to be loaded?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: I have seen that when the number of entities loaded into memroy exceeds a number the materialization performance goes too slow...

Answer (score 0):

Yes EF gets slow if you load too much at once.
often loading all records at once is not ideal.
The best way is to get a new context each time.
Use the **ORDERby SKIP TAKE** loop.  To get n recs skipping the already processed records.
ASSUMPTIONS: New records and deletions etc can interfere with a simple loop. So consider the conditions carefully.
sample loop

```
var done = false;
var n = 0;
while (!done) {
var MyContext = new DbContext(... your constructor params ); // easiest to dump the previous set. New each time !

var myDataBucket =  MyContext.Set<TPoco>()   // the table in question
                   .Where(t=> true) // any required logic to make sure data hasnt changed in the loop. And what if someone deletes a record  in this process ?
                   .OrderBy(t=>t.Id) // you need a sort field
                   .Skip(50*n)  //  
                   .Take(50);
 // whatever check to see if you processed everything, eg
 if (mybucket == null || !mybucket.Any()) {
                done = true;
            }

 // do something with 50 entries....
  n++  // ready for next set
 }
```

Comment: Phil: Does it mean that, if I have million records in a table, by default EF will try to bring all of them?

Comment: EF loads what you select.  So if you select 1 million rows it will try and load them. Bigger question. Why does someone need to load 1 million rows  at once ?

Comment: I do not favor selecting million records, infact, I am trying to avoid it be. however, for example say we have following code: EmployeeContext ec = new EmployeeContext(); ec.Employee.ToList(); in this case wil it load all the records?